# View a log of administration configuration changes for Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, configuration

I'm working on a Drupal 7 site and we have multiple developers and administrators accessing the site. Many times when the site breaks I can't see what was changed previously and by whom. Is there a log tracker where I can see what things were changed on the site? I know I can goto admin/content to see what content has been updated, but this isn't the case for configuration changes.

Comment: How is this question different from [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/233561/39516)?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in core, no.

One option from contrib is to use the [Journal](https://www.drupal.org/project/journal) module

> Journal module adds additional fields to all forms in a Drupal site to allow developers and site administrators to record and track all changes that have been performed to setup a site or alter its configuration.

It's not automatic (that would be too complicated, forms can obviously do just about anything and it's not obvious enough from context what every action is to be able to label it automagically), so you need to trust that your editors will fill it out correctly.

But you can make it required/able to be bypassed based on user roles, so it's a good solution to the problem.